# Django form and redirect

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-rest-framework

My code is the follwing : 
in views.py:

```
class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = project
    fields = ['project_name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'

def create_invite(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        invite_form = InviteForm(data=request.POST)
        if invite_form.is_valid():
            email1 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email1']
            email2 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email2']
            email3 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email3']
            email4 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email4']
            email5 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email5']
            for i in invite_form.cleaned_data:
                invite = Invitation.create(i)
                invite.send_invitation(request)
            print("The mail was went")
            return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : project.pk} )
        else:
            print("Your form is not valid")
    else:
        invite_form = InviteForm()
    return render(request, 'team_invite.html', {'invite_form': invite_form})
```

in form.py:

```
from django import forms


class InviteForm(forms.Form):
    email1 = forms.EmailField(label='Email 1')
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Email 2')
    email3 = forms.EmailField(label='Email 3')
    email4 = forms.EmailField(label='Email 4')
    email5 = forms.EmailField(label='Email 5')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from website import views

app_name = 'website'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^candidateIndex/$', views.CandidateIndex.as_view(), name='candidate_index'),
    url(r'^HRcreate/$', views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='HR_create'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
    url(r'^project/add/$',views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='addproject'),
    url(r'^invite/$',views.create_invite, name='addteam'),
]
```

Like you can see: I have a form that send email invites to user. Using that form I have two issues :

1) it seems that instead of taking the value in the input which is the email, it seems to take only the variable which is Email1 or Email2 ect..

2) when I try to redirect to the detail page using the project pk I get an error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'ProjectDetails' with keyword arguments '{'pk': <property object at 0x10ecf79a8>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: you show wrong code `project` never declared in your `create_invite` method

Comment: In your views, where is defined `project` in order to get `project.pk`?

Comment: sorry I added the lines

Comment: Your URL `['website/project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']` requires a parameter für `pk`. Your error messages indicates, that your call this URL with a whole `object` and not the `id` (=pk) of that object.